# Prove that image of unit sphere in arbitrary $\mathbb{R}-$ or $\mathbb{C}-$ finite-dimensional normed vector space is an ellipsoid.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $X, Y$ be ($\mathbb{R}-$ or $\mathbb{C}-$) finite-dimensional normed vector spaces, and let $L: X \to Y$ be a linear mapping (both $X$ and $Y$ are over the same field).

I need to prove that $L$ maps the unit sphere $\mathbb{S} = \{ x \in X \space | \space \space ||x||=1\}$ maps on an ellipsoid in $Y$ under $L$, then that $||L||$ (the operator norm) is the length of the longest axis of the ellipsoid, and from that conclude that every linear mapping between finite-dimensional normed vector spaces is continuous.

I understand that if $||L||$ is finite, then $L$ is Lipschitz and therefore also continuous, but the proof of the first two parts is what's bugging me.

The biggest problem that I have here is that I don't really know how to define an ellipsoid in a normed vector space. It works for the sphere, because every point on the sphere has the same norm. However, there isn't an equally easy way to define an ellipsoid in such an abstract setting.

Comment: You could define an ellipsoid as the set of vectors whose coordinates (x_1, ..., x_n) with respect to some basis of (some subspace of) R^m obey the inequality  ((x_1/a_1)^2 + ... + (x_n/a_n)^2) <= 1, for some strictly positive constants a_i.

Comment: Replacing (x_n/a_n)^2 by |x_n/a_n|^2 in the complex case.

Comment: And if $X$ isn't $\mathbb{R}^m$, then it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{dimX}$, $dimX = d$ so then if $f:X \to \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is an isomorphism, and $(e_{1}, e_{2}, ..., e_{d})$ is a basis for $X$, so I could write an ellipsoid is the set of points for which $\sum_{i=1}^{d} (\frac{f(e_{i})}{a_{i}})^2= 1$ holds. Does that make sense?

Comment: I see what you mean. A generalised ellipsoid. Perhaps this solves the problem inherent in my earlier comment. Namely that if the norm on X is not Euclidean, then L need not map the unit ball to an ellipsoid as I defined it.

Comment: Example: l_1^d, with L the identity map.

Comment: I suppose that, since all norms on a d-dimensional space are equivalent (equivalently, all d-dimensional spaces are isomorphic), it's enough to prove the result in the special case in which the domain and codomain are both Euclidean normed.

Comment: But this feels a bit like assuming what we are trying to prove.

Comment: I'm ashamed to say it but I've forgotten what is the usual method for proving that linear operators between finite-dimensional normed spaces must be bounded. I expect it can be found very well explained in Megginson's "introduction to Banach space theory".

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up and see what it says.